# docker does not run on windows error

Tags: windows, ssh, virtualbox, docker, boot2docker

I've installed docker and followed the directions here: https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/#installation but when I run boot2docker start this happens:

```
 Trying to get IP one more time
  exit status 255
 Docker client does not run on Windows for now. Please use
     "boot2docker" ssh
  to SSH into the VM instead
```

Trying boot2docker ssh results in the same 255 error. I tried to get the VM IP with boot2docker IP but that also yielded nothing - I presume because boot2locker wasn't successful in the start process.

A couple of observations...I lloked at the vm settings and there wasn't any network or storage settings specified and the memory allocation in the vm settings didn't match the values in the config (boot2docker config). The boot2docker start/stop commands work.

I'm stumped.

Comment: add b2d version & windows version and one snapshot for your virtualbox with installed boot2docker-vm

Answer (score 3):

I observed similar issue. Following steps helped me:

1. Open VirtualBox GUI.
2. Remove `boot2docker-vm` virtual machine.
3. Start `Boot2Docker Start` --- it will recreate `boot2docker-vm` virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

We had exactly this on someone's machine.

The solution for us was to find the

- Run the VirtualBox UI (C:\program files\oracle....)
- locate the VM (at the top)
- select 'power off'

Once all that was done, boot2docker started correctly again.

In extremis, you could delete the boot2docker-vm image out of virtualbox, and it ought to re-install it.

Answer (score 2):

go to the Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager, power off boot2docker-vm and start again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

just in case it helps. My problem was because boot2docker's default settings is beyond my laptop's capability (I know). I fixed the problem by changing the properties of boot2docker-vm through the VirtualBox GUI. Soon as I open thr properties I saw a few warnings at the bottom of the dialogue box, so I followed the hint and resolve those warnings, save the setttings and was able to start docker then.

I changed the CPU from 4->1, memory from 2G to 1.5G and video memory to 20M. Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed the CPU from 4->1, memory from 2G to 1.5G and video memory to 20M. Hope it helps.

Comment: At first , I couldn't edit. Getting out and redoing Virtualbox / VM=boot2docker select / right-click / Settings worked.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you didn't enable the "Virtualization" in your BIOS. boot2docker needs to install 64bit OS in Virtualbox.

Comment: The other solutions above did not work for me.  It turns out this is correct.  When trying to open the VM in virtual box after it is created I see the error "VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system..."

Comment: This is a problem too. But not the one the OP describes.

Answer (score 1):

Its worth noting I had some huge problems trying to run docker on windows. Boot2docker would install OK with VritualBox 4.3.20. I could NOT run boot2docker or docker itself.

It took me ages to figure out that I had uninstall VirtualBox 4.3.20 and use 4.3.12 instead which worked first time like a treat!

So.. for Windows boot2docker only use VirtualBox 4.3.12.