# Boot2Docker start up fails in windows

Tags: virtual-machine, docker, boot2docker

I am trying to start docker from winodws7 enterprise edition.

```
 boot2docker start
```

results

```
 Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
 ..........................................................................oooooo
 oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
 Started.
 Trying to get Docker socket one more time
 Error requesting socket: exec: "ssh": executable file not found in %PATH%
 Docker client does not run on Windows for now. Please use
 "boot2docker" ssh
 to SSH into the VM instead.
```

I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143819/docker-does-not-run-on-windows-error). But All answers doesn't help me. I have re-installed the boot2docker and powered off boot2docker-vm in Virtual machine and restarted. Virtualisation is enabled in my bios. My Sys has better capabilities.

Using 1.4.1 version.

Please Some Suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

As boot2docker complained, you don't have ssh in your path. Please add ssh.exe into Windows path (it might not be visible, but boot2docker installation includes msys-git installation which includes ssh.exe, so you need to add Git installation directory in path, e.g.

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

Comment: setx PATH "%PATH%;c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"