# Saving a Docker image with boot2docker

Tags: windows, save, docker, boot2docker

For starters, I'm pretty new to Docker. I've created a simple image which I would like to share. As publishing to the hub is not an option, I'm trying out the `docker save` command. I'm on Windows 7, so I'm using Docker with *boot2docker*. Saving an image does not work. I've tried the following commands without success:

With a Linux path:

```
docker save -o /home/image.tar image:tag
docker save image:tag > /home/image.tar
```

With a Windows path:

```
docker save -o C:/Temp/image.tar image:tag
docker save image:tag > C:/Temp/image.tar
```

Whenever I use a Linux path, boot2docker just hangs (or idles). When I use a Windows path, it says "*no such file or directory*".

What am I missing here? Thanks.

**EDIT**

When I run docker in debug mode, I'm getting the following output (only the last lines are pasted here). It just seems to stop...

```
EBU[0213] rendered layer for bbfcd8330926bb09da7b27af1d0d2ca001b52ff1b101c91a7287fa65072aaa64 of [84992] size
NFO[0213] -job image_tarlayer(bbfcd8330926bb09da7b27af1d0d2ca001b52ff1b101c91a7287fa65072aaa64) = OK (0)
NFO[0213] +job image_get(bbfcd8330926bb09da7b27af1d0d2ca001b52ff1b101c91a7287fa65072aaa64)
NFO[0213] -job image_get(bbfcd8330926bb09da7b27af1d0d2ca001b52ff1b101c91a7287fa65072aaa64) = OK (0)
NFO[0213] +job image_inspect(7b66ebf8de49669f1020dcdb8769f8919475aff826bc3f366ea637d5d96fd354)
NFO[0213] -job image_inspect(7b66ebf8de49669f1020dcdb8769f8919475aff826bc3f366ea637d5d96fd354) = OK (0)
NFO[0213] +job image_tarlayer(7b66ebf8de49669f1020dcdb8769f8919475aff826bc3f366ea637d5d96fd354)
EBU[0213] rendered layer for 7b66ebf8de49669f1020dcdb8769f8919475aff826bc3f366ea637d5d96fd354 of [3072] size
NFO[0213] -job image_tarlayer(7b66ebf8de49669f1020dcdb8769f8919475aff826bc3f366ea637d5d96fd354) = OK (0)
NFO[0213] +job image_get(7b66ebf8de49669f1020dcdb8769f8919475aff826bc3f366ea637d5d96fd354)
NFO[0213] -job image_get(7b66ebf8de49669f1020dcdb8769f8919475aff826bc3f366ea637d5d96fd354) = OK (0)
NFO[0213] +job image_inspect(7409a59cd6a36265e3548b778dd2eb7e6ae3043a5532770d4468d1812d8561ff)
NFO[0213] -job image_inspect(7409a59cd6a36265e3548b778dd2eb7e6ae3043a5532770d4468d1812d8561ff) = OK (0)
NFO[0213] +job image_tarlayer(7409a59cd6a36265e3548b778dd2eb7e6ae3043a5532770d4468d1812d8561ff)
EBU[0213] rendered layer for 7409a59cd6a36265e3548b778dd2eb7e6ae3043a5532770d4468d1812d8561ff of [3584] size
NFO[0213] -job image_tarlayer(7409a59cd6a36265e3548b778dd2eb7e6ae3043a5532770d4468d1812d8561ff) = OK (0)
NFO[0213] +job image_get(7409a59cd6a36265e3548b778dd2eb7e6ae3043a5532770d4468d1812d8561ff)
NFO[0213] -job image_get(7409a59cd6a36265e3548b778dd2eb7e6ae3043a5532770d4468d1812d8561ff) = OK (0)
NFO[0213] +job image_inspect(c47858ae54b487c13117fc78daeb6e871693d1c5f23d51440934940c874bed0a)
NFO[0213] -job image_inspect(c47858ae54b487c13117fc78daeb6e871693d1c5f23d51440934940c874bed0a) = OK (0)
NFO[0213] +job image_tarlayer(c47858ae54b487c13117fc78daeb6e871693d1c5f23d51440934940c874bed0a)
```

**EDIT 2**

After a while, the connection seems to be lost (no surprise...)

```
Connection to localhost closed by remote host.
error in run: exit status 65535
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Pipe viewer to check what is going on with, for example, `docker save image:tag | pv > /home/image.tar` and you will see the rate of the copy.  And I wonder if the Windows syntax should be something like `docker save -o C:\Temp\image.tar image:tag`   (to install Pipe Viewer on Linux, `sudo apt-get install pv` , or check http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml)

Comment: You are right about the Windows paths, should have noticed that... When I change the slashes to backslashes, I'm seeing the same behavior as with the Linux paths. How can I install pv, when even apt-get isn't available in boot2docker?

Comment: I had overlooked boot2docker is not a full Linux :-( What is the size of your image ? How long did you wait before giving up on `docker save` ? Check with `docker events` what is going on, see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#events

Comment: I've waited 10 minutes for 650 MB so that shouldn't be an issue. Not sure how I should execute `docker events` when `docker save` is idle (or whatever it is doing). My key strokes aren't picked up in the console while it's running.

Comment: launch at any time `docker events --since '2015-03-03'` and see what it shows.

Comment: It shows me nothing. What's strange though, is that I can still access the console and type whatever I want (it does not respond to what I typ). And that's exactly the behavior I'm seeing when I run the `docker save` command. Maybe something else is going on here?

Comment: kill -9 the docker daemon, and restart it in debug mode `To run the daemon with debug output, use docker -d -D.` (extract from https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/)

Comment: Please see my updated question for debug logs. Everything is going just fine, until its stops without any apparent reason. I'm doing all this via SSH (`boot2docker ssh`), is that maybe a clue?

Comment: maybe `boot2docker init` will help (no guarantee, use at your own risk)

Comment: That outputs `Virtual machine boot2docker-vm already exists`. Seems Docker doesn't play nice on my machine...

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143819/docker-does-not-run-on-windows-error can help